# Determine if UITableView has static cells or dynamic prototypes programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm writing an abstract UITableViewController class and I'd like to write something in `viewDidLoad` like

```
if (self.tableView.contentType == UITableViewContentTypeStaticCells) {
    // Do something when table view has static cells
} else {
    // Do something when table view has dynamic prototypes
}
```

But obviously there is no `contentType` on UITableView.  Is there a way to determine programmatically whether the tableView's storyboard content is static or dynamic?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain *why* static/dynamic cells should be treated differently. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a reasonable question, however I don't think it's relevant to what I'm asking.  I'd like to know if it's possible to distinguish between the two types of storyboard table views programmatically.  If it isn't, that's the appropriate answer. :)

Comment: It's interesting to know for e.g. localization purposes. You might want to automatically localize static cells, but not dynamic ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no build in way to distinguish between the two, but if you're more specific about what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to suggest alternative ways of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I was looking for.  I am not asking for alternative ways to accomplish my specific goal, I already have a few in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the curious: `[tableViewController valueForKey: @"staticDataSource"]` will get you there, where tableViewController is a UITableViewController.

BUT(!) this might not pass the AppStore and may break without warning as it's not published API.

Update: It seems that checking if checking, if

```
self == self.tableView.dataSource
```

while self is a UITableViewController also gives you re requested result.

Answer (score 0):

my solution assumes the abstract UITableViewController class must expose a BOOL property

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL staticCells;
```

this property is valorised by the concrete classes, and the datasource methods implementation checks the property's existence condition like in this case:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.staticCells) {
        ...
    }
    else{
        UITableViewCell* cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

I suppose you were looking for a system framework property (or delegate method) to check the static behaviour but maybe this solution can be useful for someone